# Trying to do a JOIN in Tableau getting error

Tags: sql, excel, tableau-api

I'm trying to do a "Join" by connecting a database and excel sheet then basically matching two different rows and see which is the same so the data can be put in the right place.

But I am getting this error.

https://i.redd.it/7dg6s9r7oek31.png

Im assuming bigint is SQL which I can't change to text because it's a company database. What can I do on the excel sheet so that they can look up each other?

Answer (score 0):

You could try highlighting the column in Excel and changing the formatting to 'Number'. After changing the formatting, save the Excel file as a .csv instead of an .xls or .xlsx file and try joining it to the database connection as a 'Text File' in Tableau instead of an 'Excel File' and it should work.